# How can i get MQTTS working with STM32F411 with W5500

Tags: mqtt, stm32, stm32f4, mqtt-over-websockets

Unable to get MQTTS connection with STM32F411 and W5500

I am trying to make MQTTS connection by W5500 chip. I am using STM32F411 and generating code with STM32CubeMX and compiling with Makefile. I’m unable to find any sample code that works for this, Please share if anyone have any idea how can i make this possible. I alredy tried and I have MQTT working with this setup but unable to find any example showing how would i proceed with certificates and key while connecting MQTT over secure port.
I tried with [paho-mqtt-embedded-c](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.embedded-c) libarary but in that I was not able to find a way of working with certificates.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work this way, asking for links to samples is explicitly off topic. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76380880/edit) to show what you've tried and explain how it's not working (what errors you see) and somebody may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.